# my newbie user login with Angularjs. What is the best practice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am an Angularjs newbie, so I tried to implement the user authentication in the following way. It works, but I guess it is not the best way to do it, so I am asking for a better way to implement it.

This is my way:

I have this module dependencies structure:

```
 -------       --------        ------        -----
|  app  | --> | shared |  --> |navbar|  --> |login|
 -------       --------        ------        -----
```

Where `shared` has shared components used in different pages of the app.
`navbar` has the components of the navbar and the current user, while `login` has all the components (forms, controllers, etc.) relative to the login.

I have a `CurrentUserController` where to store user info. It has a function `isLogged()` to know if it is already logged in. I bind it to the `$scope` doing `$scope.userCtrl=self`, so it is accessible from all over the app. Moreover I use the controller in the body with `ng-controller="CurrentUserController"`.

```
angular.module('navbarModule')
.controller('CurrentUserController', function ($scope) 
  {
   // initialization
   var self = this;
   $scope.userCtrl = self;
   this.islogged=false;
   this.name="";

   // functions
   this.isLogged = function() 
        { return self.islogged; };

   this.setLoggedIn = function(credentials) 
        {
         self.islogged = true; 
         self.name=credentials.email;
        }; 

   this.setLoggedOut = function() 
        { self.islogged = false; };         

  }
```

Then I have a `LoginController` that I use in the login form. It has the login() function invoked by submitting the login form. To keep things easy,I skip server request. Let's assume that when I submit, I invoke the `login()` function below passing in the credentials, and the user gets immediately logged by invoking `$scope.userCtrl.setLoggedIn()`.

```
angular.module('loginModule')

.controller('LoginController', function ($scope)
    {
     var self = this;
     self.credentials=           
          {
              email : "",
              psw: ""
          };    
     self.login = function()
            {
              $scope.userCtrl.setLoggedIn(self.credentials);
            };                      
    })
```

In the navbar element, I have a `ng-switch` directive checking if the user is already logged or not

```
<div id="nav-right-side" class="navbar-right" ng-switch on="userCtrl.isLogged()">
  <div ng-switch-when="false">
   <login-button></login-button> <!-- login/signup btn-->
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <loggedin-button></loggedin-button> <!-- user photo-->
  </div>                                                                    
</div>
```

It works well actually, but I feel that it is not the best way to implement it. I guess this way has potential security issues. What is the best practice to do that?
Thank you

Comment: If you refresh though you have to log back in again, right?

Comment: yes, right. But I think I could solve this using cookies

Answer (score 0):

I would go with JWT authentication.
There is a great implementation here : [Angular JWT Authentication](https://github.com/auth0/angularjs-jwt-authentication-tutorial)

Note that this handles the authentication on the back end and passes a token to angular to hold on it.  It also runs node.js in the back.

There is also a very nice auth setup here: [sails + angular authentication](https://github.com/Foxandxss/sails-angular-jwt-example).
It uses JWT as well.  Sails is a whole other animal though, but awesome once you get to know it a bit.

If you implement a solution like this, you have server-side confirmation that a user is authenticated.  You also get persisting sessions, so that people don't have to log in unless they log out. You can also set expirations on the tokens if you want.

Comment: thank you @tpie. I was looking for a best practice just about organizing client side angular components, avoiding security issues. However your suggestion is very interesting, thank you. I'll check it out

Comment: Where is your user data being stored?  Is it encrypted?

Comment: The sails app is laid out very well.  Explore that a bit.

Comment: server side is not implemented yet. However, it should be encrypted. I plan to use Mongo and Node.js. So I could consider your JWT proposal. I am also interested in a pure angular solution